# Western Canadian Select oil is now trading at negative

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

I just saw [this news (Twitter)](https://twitter.com/jkenney/status/1252092162126184449?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1252092162126184449&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbc.ca%2Fnews%2Fbusiness%2Foil-price-monday-1.5538048) that Western Canadian Select (WCS) oil is now trading at negative. Is WCS a public traded thing that we can buy and sell on Questrade like any other stocks? I looked on Questrade, and it doesn't appear that it is a stock. Any ideas if it is public traded and how to buy it?

Comment: WTI oil went negative but that's for the contract expiring tomorrow as April 21, 2020 . Ticker USO rolls out of the current contract with two-weeks remaining. Also, they begin as 80% current contract and 20% next dated contract.

Comment: If you did succeed in buying it what would you do with it?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a stock - it's the spot price for this particular blend of crude oil. Can you buy it? Sure, but you have to be able to *store it*.  Unless you have a few thousand 55-gallon drums in your backyard this will be a problem for you.